# Passing useState value through parent component using react hooks (getting = undefined)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-component, use-state

I'm working in a project already began that's using react class version. I plan to work with react hooks, so to don't refactor all the classes, as I write new codes, I'm trying to mix those react versions (idk if it's a good idea and I should refactor all).

I'm creating a list with pagination and search. The pagination and search are in an unique component.

To this component a need pass the search character value input by user, and here is where I'm facing problem. **In other words, I need pass a value to the parent component.**

Code is below:

**useState hook:**

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
```

**Filter component, that change the `search` value:**

```
const Filter = () => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Form.Group label="Filtro">
          <Grid.Row gutters="xs">
            <Grid.Col>
              <Form.Input
                name='search'
                placeholder='Filtro'
                autoFocus
                value={search}
                onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Grid.Col>
            <Grid.Col auto>
              <Button
                color="success"
                icon="search"
                onClick={filtrar}
              >
              </Button>
            </Grid.Col>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Form.Group>
      </Card>
    );
  }

function getSearchDB() {
    setSearch((search) => {
      return search;
    })
  }
```

**Pagination component, that receive the props:**

```
<Pagination
  baseUrl={'vehicles/toUse'}
  updateState={setStateDB}
  getSearch={getSearchDB}
  fields={'license_plate'}
/>
```

**Printing `search` value pass through Pagination component:**

```
console.log(this.props.getSearch()) //print undefined
```

**OBS:** `updateState={setStateDB}` is working fine.

**Things done to make this work (no success):**

- In `getSearch={getSearchDB}` directly pass search value. Result: `this.props.getSearch()` print undefined
- Defined getSearchDB() to be like:

  function getSearchDB() {
  return search;
  }

Result: `this.props.getSearch()` print undefined.

Is there a way to put it to work?

Guys, let me know if the post is confusion or the English is poorly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing down a function that returns `search`, why not just pass down `search` itself as a prop?

```
<Pagination
  search={search}
```

```
const Pagination = (props) => {
  console.log(props.search);
```

Comment: My Pagination component is using `Class` and `constructor(props)` to manipule props. `console.log(props.search);` continues throwing `undefined`. Tried this in constructor `search: props.search` to print `console.log(this.state.search);`, but also got `undefined`.

Comment: Tried with this: `<Pagination
  search={search}`

Comment: Since `search` starts out as the empty string, it should not ever be `undefined` unless you do `setSearch();` or something like that

Comment: I was doing it wrong. It worked how @CertainPerformance showed.

Answer (score 0):

add :

```
   <Pagination
   search={search}
/>
```

In component Pagination :

```
    const Pagination = ({search}) => {
         console.log(search);
         return {
         //...
         }
     }
```